# Getting error in while running nodeJS application in Ethereum

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, web-applications, ethereum

when I do npm run dev
The following error comes up:-

rj24@rishi-g5:~/CrowdFunding-Ethereum$ sudo npm run dev
[sudo] password for rj24:

> crowdfund@1.0.0 dev /home/rj24/CrowdFunding-Ethereum
> node server.js

(node:24992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'access' of undefined
at fileExists (/home/rj24/CrowdFunding-Ethereum/node_modules/next/dist/lib/file-exists.js:1:211)
at verifyTypeScriptSetup (/home/rj24/CrowdFunding-Ethereum/node_modules/next/dist/lib/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:1:3167)
at DevServer.prepare (/home/rj24/CrowdFunding-Ethereum/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-dev-server.js:10:1908)
at Object. (/home/rj24/CrowdFunding-Ethereum/server.js:13:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
(node:24992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
(node:24992) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library that you are using (next), is trying to use the fs Promises API, and this API is available only on node version 10 and above.

Try running `node -v` to see the version of node you are currently using.

If you have nvm installed you can "switch" to a different version of node running `nvm use v10` or `nvm use v11`. If you don't have these versions installed you can install by running `nvm install v10`.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! I m a newbie so excuse me if this seemed like a very basic doubt  thanks